# In Java Program Scanner is Working only once whereas i/ve used it twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student1{
    int a;
    String b;
    void get(int c, String d){
        a = c;
        b = d;
    }
    void show(){
        System.out.print("Id is " + a +"\n");
        System.out.print("Name is " + b);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Id");
        int e = one.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Your Name");
        String f = one.nextLine();
        Student1 s = new Student1();
        s.get(e ,f);
        s.show();
    }
}
```

when the program is executed it only asks for Id after that it shows result it never asks for Name

Comment: int e = one.nextInt(); just replace your this line with this one int e = Integer.parseInt(one.nextLine());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it gets complicated when you use `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` together. you can try this version which only uses `nextLine()`;

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Id");
    String number =one.nextLine();
    int e = Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.print("Enter Your Name");
    String f = one.nextLine();
    Student1 s = new Student1();
    s.get(e ,f);
    s.show();
}
```

**why nextInt() and nextline() produce some problems:**

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: why does it get complicated?

Comment: @user4641842 I've added a link to the answer regarding your question

Answer (score 1):

You must be entering a newline after integer. For that that blank string is acting as input for `one.nextLine()`. To avoid that one way is to add one more `one.nextLine()` statement before `String f = one.nextLine()`;

Answer (score 0):

Use only `nextLine()` method and the change the below lines of your code too for efficient

```
  Student1 s = new Student1();
    s.get(e ,f);
```

create constructor for Student1 class

```
  Student1(int c, String d)
    {
      a = c;
      b = d;
    }
```

Inside main() method

```
Student1 s = new Student1(e,f);
```

You can initialize the variables at the time of creating object by using constructor.